# Subquery returned more than 1 value using IN and ISNULL commands

Tags: sql

I need help running a SQL query I am getting this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is the query I tried to run:

```
select * 
from [Group] 
where [Group].Name IN (ISNULL((Select * from Split(@AdGroups)), [Group].Name))
```

Edit:

If `@AdGroups` is `NULL` I need all the rows in the `Group` table but IF it has any names in it I need rows with only those names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Select * from Split(@AdGroups) returns more then one row.  This subquery is used as an argument to ISNULL.  ISNULL only take a single value, checks if it is null, and returns the second value if the first value is null.  It can't handle multiple values.

I don't believe you need the is null.

```
select * from [Group] where [Group].Name IN ( * from Split(@AdGroups))
```

If this query doesn't provide the needed results, please show the wrong results and the desired results in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `isnull()` logic into the subquery:

```
select *
from [Group] g
where g.Name IN (Select coalesce(t.name, g.Name)
                 from Split(@AdGroups)) as t(name)
                )
```